# Infinite calls to the callback from useEffect when the state changes for the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, mutation

I have a parent component that passes a callback function to child component so that whenever the state of an array changes in child component, the callback will be called.
For some reason, whenever the first time I change the state in child component, it leads to an infinite loop where the callback keeps getting called forever.

Here is the real code below.

I have defined a mutation to set the list of similarBooks when user adds a new book in the list. Child component keeps track of the list. Initial value of similarBooks is provided by parent component. Child component has a form to add books into the similarBooks list. Whenever the state of that list changes, useEffect in child component gets called which in turn calls the callback function provided by the parent function. The callback function executes the setSimilarBooks mutation.

One interesting thing is that if I just move onChangeSimilarBooks callback into the Child component, then the issue doesn't exist anymore. Or if I keep the callback in parent, but don't call the setSimilarBooks mutation, then also issue disappears.

**Parent component:**

```
const [setSimilarBooks, { data: mutationSimilarBooksData, 
      loading: mutationSimilarBooksLoading, error: mutationSimilarBooksError }] 
         = useMutation(setSimilarBooksMutation);
const onChangeSimilarBooks = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    if (!mutationSimilarBooksLoading) {
        setSimilarBooks({
            variables: {
                bookId: bookId,
                similarBooksIds: values.map(value => value.id),
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Parent has a child component:

```
<ChipsComponent
                key="{bookDetails.book.name}_similarbooks"
                initialValues={bookDetails.book.similarBooks}
                suggestions={booksList.books}
                allowNew={false}
                onChangeCallback={onChangeSimilarBooks}
                userFriendlyValue={userFriendlyValueOfBook}
            />
```

Child Component:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
useEffect(() => {
    onChangeCallback(values);
}, [values]);

...


...

return (
    <div className="container">
        {values.map((book, index) => (
            <div className="books" key={index}>
                {userFriendlyValue(book)}
                <button onClick={() => deleteTag(index)}>x</button>
            </div>
        ))}
        <div className="newTag">
            <input
                value={input}
                placeholder="Enter a tag"
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            {suggestionsActive && <Autocomplete />}
        </div>

    </div>);
```

I would like for the callback to get called only once every time the state really changes.

Comment: What is `userFriendlyValue(book)` doing in the render in the child component? It seems very suspect to me. What is `userFriendlyValueOfBook` in the parent? Please include all relevant code in  a [mcve] in your post.

Comment: `book` is an object of custom type that has fields like title, similarBooks, id, etc. But for users to identify a book, just the title is enough. So userFriendlyValue takes book as input and returns title as output.
I will try how I can make the above example more minimal.
One interesting thing is that if I just move onChangeSimilarBooks callback into the Child component, then the issue doesn't exist anymore.
Or if I keep the callback in parent, but don't call the setSimilarBooks mutation, then also issue disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Reference to the function `onChangeSimilarBook` changes every render. You have somehow make it stable by reference. You could try to use `useEvent`.

[useevent.md](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md)

Answer (score 0):

It's not overtly clear why moving the callback and `useMutation` hook into the child and calling `setSimilarBooks` directly, or keeping the callback in the parent and not calling `setSimilarBooks` would trigger this. The only possibility I see from the code is that the `onChangeSimilarBooks` callback isn't a stable reference. You could wrap it in a `useCallback` hook to memoize it.

Example:

```
const onChangeSimilarBooks = useCallback((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  if (!mutationSimilarBooksLoading) {
    setSimilarBooks({
      variables: {
        bookId,
        similarBooksIds: values.map(value => value.id),
      },
    });
  }
}, [mutationSimilarBooksLoading, setSimilarBooks]);
```